# UITableViewDiffabledatasource NSFetchedResultController: how to update in case of change

Tags: uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I'm setting up a tableView with the new UITableViewDiffabledatasource and an NSFetchedResultController.

Insertion and deletion are correctly being handle out of the box. But when an item is updated (as in one of it's property is updated) and the cell displaying that item should be updated, it does not get updated.

How can I got about making sure the UITableViewDiffabledatasource sees that change and fires a refresh of the cell?

Adding the code I'm using:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = dataSource
}

func makeDataSource() -> UITableViewDiffableDataSource<String, NSManagedObjectID> {
    let reuseIdentifier = String(describing: RegisterTableCell.self)

    let dataSource =  UITableViewDiffableDataSource<String, NSManagedObjectID>(
        tableView: tableView,
        cellProvider: {  tableView, indexPath, objectID in
            let cartItem = try! self.container.viewContext.existingObject(with: objectID) as! CartItem
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                for: indexPath
            ) as! RegisterTableCell

            cell.count.text = String(format: "%@", cartItem.count ?? "0")
            cell.label.text = cartItem.name
            cell.price.text = self.priceFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: cartItem.totalPrice()))
            return cell
        }
    )
    dataSource.defaultRowAnimation = .left
    return dataSource
}


func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeContentWith snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference) {
    updateUI()
    let diffableSnapshot = snapshot as NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String,NSManagedObjectID>
    dataSource.apply(diffableSnapshot, animatingDifferences: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Could you please show some code of struct, class or enums used for datasource? This can make us understand if you are missing at some point.

Comment: @NisargShah code added

Comment: Try with `animatingDifferences: false`.
I was getting the same result (not redrawing visible cells where only the NSManagedObject attributes have changed) but removing animation seemed to fix it.
Possibly a bug in the new framework?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but a little tip I discovered… you can use `UITableViewDiffableDataSourceReference` instead of `UITableViewDiffableDataSource<String, NSManagedObjectID>` which saves a cast in `didChangeContentWith snapshot:`